# Rails 3.2 Heroku PG Error - 'operator does not exist: integer == integer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

This works in my dev environment, but when I try to run via Heroku with Postgres I get this error.

```
2012-04-07T21:35:14+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid 
  (PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer == integer 
2012-04-07T21:35:14+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...."value") AS avg_id FROM "datapoints"  
  WHERE (habit_id == 1) 
2012-04-07T21:35:14+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts. 
2012-04-07T21:35:14+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  AVG("datapoints"."value") AS avg_id FROM "datapoints 
  WHERE (habit_id == 1)):
```

Below is the line of code from my controller:

```
Datapoint.average(:value, :conditions => ['habit_id == ?', self.habit_id])
```

I'm fairly new to rails so this could easily be a very simple mistake - any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a single equals sign.

Postgresql (and the SQL standard) uses a single equals sign (=) for comparison:   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-comparison.html

Unlike a programming language, SQL doesn't need to support using it for assignment except in update clauses.  So, it doesn't require the double-equals operator (==) for comparison that most programming languages require.